# Is is possible to create a view based on a table in a different server?

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, azure-sql-database

My client have an azure service app `MyServiceApp`, its database called `MyCloudServer` (its data is taken from a legacy `MyPremiseServer`).

The `MyPremiseServer` is a server located on my client's site, because the cloud's service app `MyServiceApp` can't access it, They created the `MyCloudServer` with the exact same scheme of `MyPremiseServer`.

In order to make the `MyCloudServer` to hold the same data of `MyPremiseServer`, they developed a `MyCopyService` which is a periodic .net service that just bulk copy each one of the data of `MyPremiseServer` into `MyCloudServer`, it does it with accessing the `MyPremiseServer` views with entity-framework, and just bulk copy into the correspond view in `MyCloudServer` which has two databases: `MyDb` and `MyDbMirror` (the copy process tells the app service to stop using the `MyDb`, and start using `MyDbMirror` while the copy process is in progress, delete the old data inside each table, bulk copy it from the correspond table in `MyPremiseServer` and by the end tells the app service it can start using again the `MyDb` instead of  `MyDbMirror`).

The copy whole process is being executed once in a hour which is causes the app service data to use a not fully updated data (from last hour), and the copy process cost me a lot of effort to maintain, so my question is: **Is it possible to create a view in `MyCloudServer` that will be based upon a view located in `MyPremiseServer`** (a different server)?

I know for sure is can be done for querying a table in another database like:

```
USE [DatabaseA]
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[MyView]
AS
SELECT        DatabaseB.dbo.Events.*
FROM            DatabaseB.dbo.Events
GO
```

Comment: I'm curious as to why you are asking us instead of trying it?

Comment: Hey @DaleK, trying what? all I was able to find how to manually import from another server using the sql wizard

Comment: Try "Is it possible to create a view in MyCloudServer that will be based upon a view located in MyPremiseServer"

Comment: Just a guess: if your app on Azure cannot access the db on the onprem server, possibly behind a firewall and not exposed on the internet, there is no way to reach it also for the db server on the cloud. even if it would be possible to create a view on a linked server on the db, the linked server should be reachable, and likely this is not the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot create linked server in Azure SQL.

You can sync data between on-premises server & Azure SQL, using below approaches:

- [SQL Data Sync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/sql-data-sync-data-sql-server-sql-database)
- [Azure Data Factory pipeline](https://www.element61.be/en/resource/building-hybrid-cloud-syncing-premise-databases-microsoft-azure-cloud-using-azure-data)
- Create a linked server in `MyPremisesServer` and merge to `MyCloudServer` as regular job [Create linked server in onpremises](https://sqlpowered.com/linked-server-from-on-premise-to-azure-sql-database/)